# How to mesure lengths and areas in other euclidean, spherical and hyperbolic geometry?

Tags: geometry

I am learning how to measure lengths an areas in euclidean, spherical and hyperbolic geometry, but I'm getting very confused.

First of all, I am told a rectifiable curve $\gamma$ has length defined by $$\int_{\gamma} ds$$ and a Borel set $B$ has area defined by $$\iint_{B} ds^{2},$$ where $ds$ and $ds^{2}$ are the arclength and area elements of each particular geometry. So in the euclidean case we have $ds = \left| dz \right| = \sqrt{dx^{2} + dy^{2}}$ and $ds^{2} = dx dy;$ in the spherical case we have $ds = \frac{2 \left| dz \right|}{1 + \left| z \right|^{2}}$ and $ds^{2} = \frac{4 dx dy}{(1 + \left| z \right|^{2})^{2}};$ and for the hyperbolic case we have $ds = \frac{2 \left| dz \right|}{1 - \left| z \right|^{2}}$ and $ds^{2} = \frac{4 dx dy}{(1 - \left| z \right|^{2})^{2}}.$

Now, my problem is that I don't know how to make sense of this were I given a curve $\gamma$ or a set $B.$ How can I put these formulas to work in practice?

Answer (score 1):

Well you simply make the replacements in the formulas. For example
if $\gamma(t) = \langle x(t), y(t)\rangle$ where $a \le t \le b$ then you just start substituting

$$\int_{\gamma} ds = \int_{\gamma} \frac{2 \left| dz \right|}{1 + \left| z \right|^{2}} = \int_{\gamma} \frac{2 \sqrt{dx^2 + dy^2}}{1 + x^2 + y^2} = \int_a^b \frac{2 \sqrt{x'(t)^2 + y'(t)^2}}{1 + x(t)^2 + y(t)^2} dt$$